# React - prevent lifecycle components from rendering the same data twice: WillReceiveProps & componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Quick React question for Components specifically. I am using two lifecycle methods:

- componentDidMount() -for retrieving data when component is first rendered
- componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)  - for updating data when some parameters change

This works great. However, when I refresh the page with the component, both lifecycle methods are executed when one will suffice. The data on page is still correct, however it seems a bit inefficient. How can I combine these to lifecycles if possible?

Below example will call  **fetchTest() twice** when page is refreshed. If I remove componentDidMount, then the data will not initially load if user refreshes the page.

Any ideas on how to have fetchTest() called once no matter how the user gets to the component?

```
 componentDidMount() {
     fetchTest(this.props.params.id);
     // for initial component render
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     fetchTest(nextProps.params.id);
     // for when (params.id) is changed. data within component is updated
   }
```

Comment: Your question is oddly worded. If you want to guarantee `fetchTest` is only called once, then don't include `componentWillReceiveProps` at all.. but if you want to maintain the behaviour of calling `fetchTest` when new `params`, compare `this.props.params` with `next.props.params` to see if the id is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id) {
    fetchTest(nextProps.params.id);
  }
}
```